# two values by using checkboxes

Tags: angularjs

I have a question:

if I use the checkboxes, I can choose only one value

[plunk example](http://plnkr.co/edit/rXJaU3kkvYstXQh8MkIU?p=preview)

```
 <input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="Korman Juriy" ng-false-value="" ng:model="query.name"/>
```

or

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="Ananchenko Juriy" ng-false-value="" ng:model="query.name"/>
```

how to get the two values together?

Comment: What do you mean by "get the two values together"? Do you want to filter by both chosen values? And if so, do you want filter by `checkbox1 AND checkbox2` or by `checkbox1 OR checkbox2`?

Comment: forgive me my poor English, I mean - checkbox1 AND checkbox2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the best way is to create 2 diferent variables, like "name1" and "name2", instead "name" in both of the checkboxes.
So, in the first line

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="Korman Juriy" ng-false-value="" ng:model="query.name1"/>

<input type="checkbox" ng-true-value="Ananchenko Juriy" ng-false-value="" ng:model="query.name2"/>
```

Hope it helps your propose.

Comment: thank you but this method is not suitable to me to solve the problem

Comment: thank you but this method is not suitable to me to solve the problem, because in the template used only {{emp.name}}

Answer (score 0):

the best of the solutions that I have found:

```
jsfiddle.net/mattdwen/u5eBH/2/
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but it's not my example, do I have the right to publish it here?

Comment: @user3266329 Yes, as long as you don't claim it to be yours.